# Reverse Enginner Sound Morphing?

Tags: voice

I came across the concept of sound morphing recently and after looking briefly into it, I wonder if its possible to reverse engineer it and obtain the original voice. Personally i dont think that it is possible to reverse engineer it, since every attempt to revert it back would result in a voice which can be considered a legitimate one. I understand that most there can be a claim that most would not fall into a category of authentic human voices but i believe we might still get a considerable number of valid outputs.

Apart from that i believe there are softwares which given any input and a target output voice can transform that input to given output. This make my believe stronger since that would mean that we can map any voice to any other voice.

I believe voice morphing is like a one way function. We can go in one direction but its impossible to revert back since almost every answer would fall into the category of valid answer.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong and thank you in advance :)

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'sound morphing'?

Comment: i am sorry, may be i shudnt have used sound morphing. I mean changing from one voice to another voice for ex: from person A's voice to person B's voice.

Comment: In theory this should be possible if no information is permanently removed from B's voice. Then (only if you know what has been done to A's voice) you could reverse the process. But this means that you need a software capable of doing this and I don't a program that could achieve this. So in theory: yes you can but in practice: no you can't.